# How to use WHERE and GROUP BY statements in MySQL script?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which includes field ***model*** and ***mainid***. I want to get particular ***model*** and group them by ***mainid***.

I used syntax

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE model = 18
```

And I get following result

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [mainid] => 102
        [model] => 18
     )
   [1] => Array
    (
        [mainid] => 102
        [model] => 18
     )
   [2] => Array
    (
        [mainid] => 104
        [model] => 18
      )
   [3] => Array
    (
        [mainid] => 105
        [model] => 18
      )
  }
```

I tried using following syntax

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE model = 18 GROUP BY mainid
```

And it gives 0 rows.

I want result as following

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array
    (
        [mainid] => 102
        [model] => 18
    )
 [1] => Array 
    (
        [mainid] => 105
        [model] => 18
    )
 [2] => array
    (
         [mainid] => 105
         [model] => 18
    )
 }
```

Comment: group by is  used  with aggregate functions so if you want to do any group operations such as sum,avg,count then you should use group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY is usually used along with aggregate functions.
Try using SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table WHERE model = 18
It might help you in this case.